# ERROR Unexpected literal at position 2 when I used <p-calendar> from PrimeNG in Angular 9

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a reactive form made with Angular and PrimeNG. To get the data I used `<p-calendar>` and not problem. My problem begin when I try to retrieve the data. This is the error:

```
core.js:6260 ERROR Unexpected literal at position 2.
```

This is part of my code:

formulario.component.ts

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  'fechaEntrada': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
})
```

formulario.component.html

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
   <label for="fechaEntrada">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
   <p-calendar formControlName="fechaEntrada" showButtonBar="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

From `package.json` my Angular and PrimeNG versions config:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "primeflex": "^1.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.2",
```

Any idea about it or advice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. The error in the code you posted is that you are initializing your form control with empty string, but since p-calendar accepts Date values you should initialize it with null.

The error message that you wrote comes from binding the form with date string instead of Date object.